# temp DB file does not exist after moving

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I am using SQL server 2019 AG.

I am facing an issue after moving temp DB files from one drive to another after locating the file paths by this script:

```
    Use master
    GO
    
    SELECT 
    name AS [LogicalName]
    ,physical_name AS [Location]
    ,state_desc AS [Status]
    FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'tempdb');
    GO
```

there were 9 files

then I use to move them :

```
 USE master;
    GO
    
    ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'T:\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf');
    GO
    
    ALTER DATABASE tempdb 
    MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'T:\MSSQL\DATA\templog.ldf');
    GO
 

   ALTER DATABASE tempdb
MODIFY FILE (NAME = temp2, FILENAME = ‘T:\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb_mssql_2.ndf’);
GO
```

I run this for all 8 files, after that I run the first script again I did not find the rest of the files I just found tempdev, and templog .
and I run the moving script again :

```
"MODIFY FILE failed. File 'temp2' does not exist"
```

so I lost all the rest of the 9 files !!
7 files are missing

- is there any way I can reattach these files?
- is my SQL server will work fine with only 2 files log and DB?

Comment: Did you restart the instance after the move script in order to create the new tempdb files?

Comment: Agree with Dan. Not doing a re-start after the move script would perfectly explain the posted behaviour.

Comment: I did, I restarted the SQL service

Answer (score 3):

You also need to check `tempdb.sys.database_files`. It's possible for there to be [metadata mismatches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_pfe_blog/tempdb-misconfiguration-when-sql-server-fails-to-create-a-secondary-data-file) between it and `sys.master_files`.